# Convert C++ code to C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++

Im having very tough challenge in converting the following code C#, can anybody help me on how do we do that.

```
typedef struct ACSNameAddr_t {
    char FAR *serverName;    // How do i use FAR in C#
    struct {
        short length;
        unsigned char FAR *value;
    } serverAddr;
} ACSNameAddr_t;
```

and how do i use this union in C#

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        CSTARouteRegisterAbortEvent_t   registerAbort;
        CSTARouteUsedEvent_t            routeUsed;
        CSTARouteUsedExtEvent_t         routeUsedExt;
        CSTARouteEndEvent_t             routeEnd;
        CSTAPrivateEvent_t              privateEvent;
        CSTASysStatEvent_t              sysStat;
        CSTASysStatEndedEvent_t         sysStatEnded;
    }u;
} CSTAEventReport;
```

Edit Answer:

So including all your answers, here by i'm writing the converted code. Please edit it if there is anything wrong, it might be useful for someone..

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
public struct ACSNameAddr_t
{
    string serverName;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct serverAddr
    {
        public short length;
        string value;
    };
};
```

and for the second one,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4)]
    public struct CSTAEventReport{
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4)]
        public struct u{
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTARouteRegisterAbortEvent_t registerAbort;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTARouteUsedEvent_t routeUsed;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTARouteUsedExtEvent_t routeUsedExt;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTARouteEndEvent_t routeEnd;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTAPrivateEvent_t privateEvent;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTASysStatEvent_t sysStat;
            [FieldOffset(0)]
            public CSTASysStatEndedEvent_t sysStatEnded;
        };
};
```

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Epic fail for both of those code snippets.

Comment: @Soner - Tried that already, not working.. If someone able to convert this, then i will be able to convert other methods. :)

Comment: `FAR` doesn't come into it for C#, it's just a character pointer.

Comment: If you are trying to translate legacy code (and not, saying, using these structures for P/Invoke), you might want to translate to C++/CLI instead of C#.

Comment: Is FAR necessary and functional in the original code? My understanding is that FAR doesn't do anything anymore. You'd need to be running on ancient hardware for it to mean anything, and .NET probably wouldn't run on that anyways. From WinDef.h (assuming you're on Windows) `#define far` (defined to nothing).

Comment: @BlueRaja - PInvoke is showing  "Nested elements not supported", Strictly i need code in C#

Comment: @Kevin - This code is in an SDK , so i shouldnt alter any of the declarations but i need to use them in C#

Comment: I suggest providing more context and narrowing the scope of your question rather than asking the community to do your work for you.  What specifically is the problem when you try to convert this to C#?

Comment: @Chandu- Indyaah - FAR is defined to nothing. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Greg - I'm newbie for this kind of conversions, dont take me wrong here , i'm just asking a part not my whole project to convert..

Comment: @Greg - I'm newbie for this kind of conversions, dont take me wrong here , i'm just asking a part not my whole project to convert.. C# is advanced and few features were removed such as unions and FAR, so im asking community alternatives for the above 2..

Comment: If you use `LayoutKind.Explicit`, then you must supply offsets for all fields. I suspect that you wanted `LayoutKind.Sequential` for the `ACSNameAddr_t` and `serverAddr` structs.

Comment: @Jim - Yes you're right.. Thanks for spotting it :) Edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So including all your answers, here by i'm writing the converted code. Please edit it if there is anything wrong, it might be useful for someone..

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)] 
public struct ACSNameAddr_t 
{ 
    string serverName; 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)] 
    public struct serverAddr 
    { 
        public short length; 
        string value; 
    }; 
};
```

and for the second one,

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4)] 
    public struct CSTAEventReport{ 
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit, Pack = 4)] 
        public struct u{ 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTARouteRegisterAbortEvent_t registerAbort; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTARouteUsedEvent_t routeUsed; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTARouteUsedExtEvent_t routeUsedExt; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTARouteEndEvent_t routeEnd; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTAPrivateEvent_t privateEvent; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTASysStatEvent_t sysStat; 
            [FieldOffset(0)] 
            public CSTASysStatEndedEvent_t sysStatEnded; 
        }; 
};
```

Answer (score 4):

`char FAR *` is just a pointer to a string. Back in the bad old days when we had to worry about different memory models, `FAR` was a 32-bit pointer and `NEAR` was a 16-bit pointer. Treat that `char FAR *` as you would any other character pointer.

Comment: Should "any other string pointer" be "any other character pointer"? Sorry for being a pedant (well actually we both know I'm not really sorry, I'm just being polite about being a pedant).

Comment: What would be the equivalent code in C# for char FAR *  ?
Sorry i dont know much of conversion part

Comment: @Chandu- Indyaah: for C#, use `string` in place of the C/C++ `char FAR *`.

Comment: @Binary Worrier: noted and changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can simulate C++ unions in C# by using StructLayout:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxa5b99(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acxa5b99%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Basically, just declare a series of variables with the same offset, which is really what a union is.

Edit: Just a copy/paste from the link to illustrate:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct TestUnion
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public int i;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public double d;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public char c;

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public byte b;
}
```